# Sort collection having key as long

Tags: java, android, collections

I use this code to sort a collection having the key as String type:

```
class Myclass { 
    String Key;
    other variables
}
```

The Collection is defined like this:

```
ArrayList<Myclass> MyCollection = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

I add some items to MyColletion, and finally sort the collection:

```
Collections.sort(MyCollection, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
        return  c1.Key.compareToIgnoreCase(c2.Key);
    }
});
```

This code works and sorts the collection if the key is a string. But I want to change my key to be a long, so the class will look like this:

```
class Myclass { 
    long Key;
    other variables
}
```

I am not able to find the code to sort a collection having the key as long type. It should have to work also with older Android apis than 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Long.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-) like this:

```
return Long.compare(c1.Key,c2.Key);
```

If the above is not supported by older Android apis than 19 then you can do:

```
Collections.sort(MyCollection, new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    @Override public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
        if(c1.Key < c2.Key) return -1;
        if(c1.Key > c2.Key) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: I get Exception "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"

Comment: @Ton This is not due to the comparator. `MyCollection` is most like an unmodifiable collection. if it needs to me unmodifiable then before sorting make a copy like so `List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<>(unmodifiableList);` then sort this new list and then create an unmodifiable list from it after it's sorted. if it doesn't need to be unmodifiable then just make your list modifiable in the first place.

Comment: You are right. My original list was a CopyOnWriteArrayList. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

**Note:this comparator will not work for primitive datatypes like int ,long,double ,yet i am giving this solution if  wrapper class is used this can be useful**

For the generic way of sorting your list values you can use this comparator

```
public class Genericcomparator<T extends Myclass> implements Comparator<T>  {

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.key.compareTo(o2.key);
    }
}
```

and use it in your class as

```
Collections.sort(list, new Genericcomparator<Myclass>());
```

so when ever you change the datatype there will be no issue in comparing it